# Display output to multiple classes via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I am writing a "Gamebook Engine" which offers the possibility of setting a user name. The Name is taken from an input with the id="setUserNameInput" and saved by the function setUserName(). It is displayed / loaded into an element containing the class="displayUserName" and loaded by the function displayUserName(). It works fine with only one class one the page, but as soon as I add more I have to define which one to target as it won't target them all automatically. I have tried to use document.getElementById, document.getElementsByName as well as document.querySelectorAll and document.querySelector, none of which work. (I use Bulma as my CSS Framework, by the way)

Here is the code I have so far (though it will show an error as it cannot access the localStorage inside the snippet):
This page http://scampsblog.com/docs/example-de.html contains an (working, haha) example. Since it is a documentation (page lies on my testing sever, thus the domain) you might want to take a look at http://scampsblog.com/docs/character-enginedotjs-de.html which explains / shows the individual elements (the documentation is in German but I can provide a translation if you need one).

The part of the JS I am struggling with is right in the first line but if you suggest some overall improvements, I will be happy to take them.

```js
var userNameOutput = document.getElementsByClassName('displayUserName')[0];

function setUserName() {
  var usernameinput = document.getElementById('setUserNameInput').value;
  localStorage.setItem('userName', usernameinput);

  if (!localStorage.getItem('userName')) {
    setUserName();
  } else {
    var storedUserName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
    userNameOutput.innerHTML = storedUserName;
  }
}


function displayUserName() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('userName')) {
    setUserName();
  } else {
    var storedUserName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
    userNameOutput.innerHTML = storedUserName;
  }
}

window.onload = function displayUserName() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('userName')) {
    setUserName();
  } else {
    var storedUserName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
    userNameOutput.innerHTML = storedUserName;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Your name goes here" id="setUserNameInput">


<input type="button" class="button" value="Set your username" onclick="setUserName()" />



<input type="button" class="button" value="Display on click" onclick="displayUserName()" />
<br> So you shall be called <span class="displayUserName"></span>! But dont worry, <span class="displayUserName"></span>, it will be all fine.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the first item in the collection (using `[0]`) you could iterate through it (using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)) and set the `innerHTML` of each element having the class `displayUserName`.

e.g.

```
var userNameOutputs = document.querySelectorAll('.displayUserName');

for (let ele of userNameOutputs) {
  ele.innerHTML = userName;
}
```

Full code, with some optimizations to structure:

```js
function setUserName() {
  var usernameinput = document.getElementById('setUserNameInput').value;
  localStorage.setItem('userName', usernameinput);
  displayUserName(true); // pass true to avoid recursion
}

function displayUserName(skipSet) {
  var userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
  
  if (!userName && !skipSet) {
    setUserName();
  } else {
    var userNameOutputs = document.querySelectorAll('.displayUserName');
    
    for (let ele of userNameOutputs) {
      ele.innerHTML = userName;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = displayUserName;
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Your name goes here" id="setUserNameInput">

<input type="button" class="button" value="Set your username" onclick="setUserName()" />

<input type="button" class="button" value="Display on click" onclick="displayUserName()" />
<br> So you shall be called <span class="displayUserName"></span>! But dont worry, <span class="displayUserName"></span>, it will be all fine.
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hosney/3pxfybrc/1/

Comment: Thanks! But I am not sure how to implement it into my code to get it working (and not break anything else -> I am pretty new to JavaScript and make this project in order to learn the language) A JSfiddle would be awesome.

Comment: Added the fiddle link

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working! May I ask how you have learned JS?

Comment: You're welcome. Mostly by working with it, answering questions and looking at answers on StackOverflow and Googling.. Also the book _JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford_ helped me get started. You might want to give it a try. Btw could you accept the answer by ticking the check next to it please?

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely take a look at that book

Answer (score 0):

var userNameOutput = document.getElementsByClassName('displayUserName')[0];

the [0] selects the first element of the array of elements of the class name.

Comment: I know, but it was the only working way (I knew) to select at least one.